# I created a program, I input keys and values to add to a dictionary but it doesn't work properly

Tags: python, list, dictionary, while-loop, format

```
liste = []
while True:
    key = input("key: ")
    val = input("val: ")
    words = ('"{}":"{}"'.format(key,val))
    liste.append(words)
    if len(liste)>=16: #I have 16 words per page
        print(liste)
```

Here is my code. It is working but when I print the list, it is like:

```
liste = ['"key1","val1"','"key2","val2"','"key3","val3"']
```

As you can see, there are prime marks (') at the beginning and end of every item. So if I copy and paste those keys and values to my dictionary it won't work. How can I delete these prime marks from my list?

Comment: `words = {key: val}` ?

Comment: Just don't store them that way in the first place. Either store them in a dict to begin with, store them in a list of tuples, store some better string format that's easily split/delimited, etc.

Comment: I think `liste` should be `dicte` you could have a single dict with keys and values (providing no duplicate keys and order unimportant). Also you need a `break` condition to exit the infinitive loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create dict also in this way:

```
words = dict()
words[key] =val
```

Or

```
words = {}
words[key] =val
```

Or using `zip`:

```
words = dict(zip(key,val)
```

Also you can see the trick what Rakesh mentioned.

Comment: I tried this and it's okay right now. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

To create a dictionary use `{key:val}`

**Ex:**

```
liste = []
while True:
    key = input("key: ")
    val = input("val: ")
    words = {key: val} 
    liste.append(words)
    if len(liste)>=16: #I have 16 words per page
        print(liste)
```

Comment: but when i use this code, output is;
    {'key1': 'val1'}, {'key2': 'val2'},  {'key3': 'val3'},  {'key4': 'val4'}
i think this is another problem